# Value of type 'NSButton' has no member 'Clicked' | Xcode error with button

Tags: swift, xcode, browser, webkit, swift5

I'm making a browser using Swift and made a refresh button, I don't know much about any coding but most about Lua. Used a tutorial for most of this, I've done everything neccessary at this point and have an image button. Keep getting this error: Value of type 'NSButton' has no member 'clicked'I need to use Swift 5 for this- Here's the code:

````
@IBAction func didrefreshButtonTapped (_ sender: NSButton) {
            if sender.clicked == 0 {
                webView.reload()
            }else {
                webView.reload()
            }
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT DON'T NEED THIS TO BE ANSWERED! I just assigned the button in FirstResponder to reload.